# Is it possible to make the Sun spin a coin in space?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, rotational-dynamics, sun

Is it possible to do anything to a coin in space, so it begins to spin, using sunlight as the energy source?

Comment: Does a solar panel connected to an electric motor count? Also connected to whatever stabilization system you need to prevent the whole thing from spinning

Comment: It will probably spin anyway. Any lack of symmetry on the coin's surface will differentially be affected by radiation pressure.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes.

Paint half (as in a filled semicircle) a face of the coin black, while leaving the other half shiny. Place the painted face parallel to the Sun's surface.

The two sides of that face will now experience different radiation pressures from the solar radiation: in particular, the still-shiny half will experience greater radiation pressure because it reflects the radiation (requiring twice the counter-momentum to conserve momentum), while the black half absorbs it (as it simply absorbs the momentum of the light), and hence a torque will be created that favors the shiny half.

Comment: Does the coin just keep spinning faster and faster until it rips itself apart? I can't think of anything that would cause the torque to change over time.

Comment: See also the weird example of the [light mill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crookes_radiometer) which paradoxically does **not** work according to this principle. (But would, if it weren't for friction and residual pressure)

Comment: It will not only rotate, but also accelerate away from the sun.

Comment: @mlk the radiometer was my first thought when seeing this question.  I read the explanation at that link and came away with the impression that radiation pressure was too low a force to work in this application.

Comment: A nontrivial part of this is that the shiny part needs to be shiny in the (near) visible spectrum, but black in the lower IR spectrum.  Otherwise, the coin will reradiate the absorbed heat chiefly from the black region (cancelling out the momentum initially absorbed)

Comment: @bogl Are you sure the gravity wouldn't win?

Comment: Valid point! @JohnDvorak

Comment: @JohnDvorak - Assuming the coin is in orbit, and pretending that there were nothing else to interact with, and that the sun would shine steady state far longer than it it actually will, the radiation pressure would slowly increase the eccentricity of the orbit until it eventually becomes hyperbolic and the coin escapes.

Comment: @NuclearWang:  Since absorpivity = emissivity at a given temperature, the coin will emit more thermal radiation from the black half than from the shiny half, which cancels the torque somewhat;  see poncho's point above.  If the coin got up to the same temperature as the Sun, I *think* it would experience zero torque — otherwise it would violate the second law of thermodynamics.  But in "practical" terms, I'm not sure that this would ever happen.

Comment: Alteration of asteroid spin by radiation pressure has been observed, and is thought to be an important factor in the evolution of small asteroidal bodies. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yarkovsky%E2%80%93O%27Keefe%E2%80%93Radzievskii%E2%80%93Paddack_effect

Comment: @NuclearWang there is probably a limit of the coin rotational speed because of the sun wind and it is probably before ripping itself apart.

Comment: @PaulSinclair why wouldn't you be able to model the (sun + solar pressure) system as just a solar-pressure-free system with slightly weaker gravity, around which you can have stable orbits?

Comment: @YonatanN: Nope. It also exerts a drag force, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting%E2%80%93Robertson_effect

Comment: @YonatanN - Ignoring for the moment the Poynting Roberson effect, the radiation pressure from the sun *adds energy* to the coin. More energy means a higher overall orbit (though I suspect I was wrong about it making the orbit more eccentric - maybe I should pull up KSP and experiment with what happens when you add a radial component to the existing velocity). Without other interactions, there is nothing to drain that energy away. so it will slowly build until it is enough to escape.

Comment: As for the Poynting Robertson effect, note that the article says it is only significant on dust. For larger grains (and a coin would be a fairly large grain), radiation pressure from the sun overwhelms it.